# Are there any HTML parsing libraries?

Tags: crystal-lang

Hey i'm looking for some html parsing libraries in crystal. Something similar to nokogiri for ruby. I have a working regular expression but would prefer a html parsing library because html + regex == bad. Thanks.

Comment: isnt nokogiri crystal compatible?

Comment: @marmeladze No ruby libraries are "crystal compatible" in the same way you can't use Java libraries from JavaScript, they're entirely different languages.

Comment: https://github.com/veelenga/awesome-crystal#htmlxml-parsing

Comment: Yes. Off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way in the Crystal standard library is [`XML.parse_html`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.22.0/XML.html). This will give you an `XML::Node` which has a pretty nice interface.

If you *need* to use CSS selectors, you can use [Crystagiri](https://github.com/madeindjs/Crystagiri), although otherwise I don't see much benefit over the stdlib's offering.

Answer (score 3):

After several hours of googling i just found out about [myhtml](https://github.com/kostya/myhtml), [modest](https://github.com/kostya/modest) and [Crystagiri](https://github.com/madeindjs/Crystagiri). All of them are HTML parsing libraries.

Comment: add pls links to your answer

Answer (score 1):

I am the creator of [Crystagiri](https://github.com/madeindjs/Crystagiri). This is an HTML parser library for Crystal (like the amazing [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) Ruby gem. I won't pretend that Crystagiri does much as Nokogiri but you can use to use CSS selector.

Bellow a basic example:

```
require "crystagiri"

doc = Crystagiri::HTML.from_url "http://example.com/"
puts doc.css("li > strong.title") { |tag| puts tag.node}
# => <strong class="title"> .. </strong>
# => <strong class="title"> .. </strong>
```

Thanks to Crystal Lang, [Crystagiri](https://github.com/madeindjs/Crystagiri) is three time faster than [Nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri) (accroding to my test).